# How to switch from one workspace to the other in Linux Mint/Ubuntu (KWin)?

Tags: kde, workspaces

I tried modifying global keyboard shotcuts (Kwin): go to Desktop X, go to Desktop right/left.

When I try the keys nothing happens.
Maybe there's a visually application to do that? (create new workspaces / switch between them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the new Plasma5, some say it has problems with keyboard shortcuts (not that I've noticed).

You can easily change workspace by using the "Desktop grid" effect. Once you have enabled it in "Desktop Effects", you can activate it both with a keybord shortcut (CTRL+F8 by default) and by navigating to a window corner, if you have set it up to do so in the "Screen Edges" menu (which you can find with KRunner).

From there you can select, add and remove workspaces.

Comment: thank you for the very detailed explanations. Unfortunately none of the options work (and they are active). neither +F8 or edges. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure desktop effects are active? Can you trigger any desktop effect?

Comment: actually I just noticed that in Desktop effects when chooking a new effect I get the error: Desktop effects not running.
I searched a solution around but couldn't find a working one

Comment: The shortcut for activating / deactivating effects is Alt+Shift+F12. Try to activate them, if they don't work (which video card do you have?) try to change rendering method. ou can do that from "display and monitor" > "compositor". Fromthere you can also tweak other compositor options, among which if effectsshould be active at startup. If the compositor finds any problems, it will turn off effects automatically to prevent crashes. This is usually due to video driver problems or very very old video cards (> 8 years old).

Comment: thank you for your further explanation. However with Alt+Shift+fn+F12 (with fn since my keyboard gives priority to multimedia options, but I actually tried with configuring simpler keyboard shortcuts) nothing happens and I can't find "display and monitor". I'm on Mint 17.2 and there are just "display" and "display configuration" + "Xserver".
My computer is pretty new, bought 1 year ago. NVIDIA GEFORCE (how do I verify what one is the specific model?) of which I upgraded the drivers couple of weeks ago

Comment: I have no idea which version of Plasma you have installed (you can check it with kinfocenter, I guess), so maybe the settings menu is slightly different. In my Plasma (5.4.1) this is the layout of the relevant part of systemsettings: http://imgur.com/qlYpySN

Comment: I can't really figure out what's wrong (probably some issue with double drivers) but I'll accept the answer for the effort

Comment: It may be a driver issue, you could try to see if switching drivers helps. It may also be due to wrong KWin settings. There is a GUI way to change them, it's strange that you don't find it. Maybe you are using an old DE version? KInfoCenter will tell you that, the latest version is 5.4.1. In the latest version, the KWin config file is .config/kwinrc, if you want to try to edit it manually. To find out which video card you have you can use lshw, KInfoCenter or any other hardware information software for Linux, google will help you with that.

Comment: For years, I've been using Ctl-Fn where "n" is the desktop I want to go to.  Of course, that is all now modulo whatever in holy heck this "activity" thingy is.  Anyway, yesterday I had an auto-update and now none *NONE* of those shortcuts work and whatever Ctl-F8 is supposed to be does nothing, too.  So, now, my per-desktop wallpaper is gone as well as a shortcut to navigate to a desktop.  :(  I am so disappointed.

Comment: @Bruce It seems like you switched from the old KDE4 to Plasma5. Plasma 5 introduced many new features and fixed many bugs, improved performance and made the desktop much more beautiful. Unfortunately, a couple of features were temporarily removed, and different backgrounds per wallpaper is one of them. As for showrtcuts, as usual you can find and edit them in "Global keyboard shortcuts" (search in Krunner), or, for desktop shortcuts, in "Virtual desktops" too. Not that hard to find!

Comment: I should have come back when I discovered the real problem:  my keyboard has an "F-Lock" key that I never use but stumble fingered it.  The stumbling was coincidental with the update.  *sigh*  Yes, I miss the different wallpapers per desktop, but they are promising to restore it in several more releases.  I just have to wait several more releases, however long that might be.....

Answer (score 0):

If you go into settings > shortcuts > global shortcuts > kwin, and then search for desktop (only necessary to show only shortcuts related to desktop in kwin, and to have the change desktop options near the top of the list). You can then set up shortcuts for going one desktop to the left, right, up or down. So depending on how you have your desktops laid out, you can re-create the gnome shortcuts here.

As you do this, if you have the `Desktop Gird` feature enabled, you will notice it here mixed in with all the other options. If you change the desktop grid shortcut the desktop effects, it will change the kwin shortcut as that is what it is using. You can also go to settings > desktop behavior > virtual desktops > switching (tab at the top) to change the desktop switching shortcuts at the bottom which, again, will actually change the kwin shortcut. All that means is that you can freely change the setting in either place to without any problems.

I usually have mine laid out in a single row, so I usually do left and right instead of up and down. you can also use next and previous desktop instead of left, right, up, and down.